# AngularJS Date Time according to eastern time

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS to get date from service 2014-09-29 and time as 191042 .

I need to show something like this

> 29 September 2014 19:10:42 ET

How do I convert it according to eastern time zone as I am getting date & time separately?

Comment: do you need this in angular? JavaScript? what angular version?

Comment: @Raduken : I want in angular JS

Comment: what version? 1 or 2?

Comment: @Raduken : Angular Js 1

Comment: @Raduken `angularjs` tag is **only** for AngularJS 1.* questions, this is in the tag description. There is `angular2` for questions about Angular2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date with timezone in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342335/format-date-with-timezone-in-angularjs)

Comment: this question doesn't entirely make sense;  firstly, are you suggesting that your API returns string values for `date` and `time`?

Answer (score -1):

You can format with a filter `{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}`, in your case: `<span>{{datevar | date:'d MMMM y'}} {{timevar | date:'HH:mm:ss' : '-0500'}} ET</span>` all the formats you find here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date. Check out at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/l7ayOKSPGJp3Uvbfgtlx?p=preview. Completing the answer, if you need to ajust in summer time you can set the local with `angular-locale` plugin as you can see at this post: [Angular JS - Date changes when submitting to $http - Timezone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356475/angular-js-date-changes-when-submitting-to-http-timezone-issue)

Comment: Thanks Luiz.But I have Date seperately and time seperately .I need to convert it according to eastern time and show as I described earlier

Comment: You can format separatedly, just the same way, you know wich timezone it is? I will ajust the answer for separated variables.

Comment: I need to show according to EST – Eastern Standard Time

Comment: Eastern Standard Time (EST) is 5 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). This time zone is in use during standard time in: North America, Caribbean, Central America.
This time zone is often called Eastern Time Zone.

Comment: Note that this answer will be incorrect for half the year when EST becomes EDT.

Comment: See, according to the question the answer is correct, and how can be known if the region change the timezone or not? other solutions may imply on servers or client clocks configuration, not on the script language.